# OpenCV: How to view existing JNI cpp bindings

Tags: c++, opencv, java-native-interface

How can you view or generate the Swig cpp bindings bundled up in the .so files for opencv?

This to see how jobjects or others, get converted and used into existing native opencv methods.

For example: A method takes 2 `java Mat` as inputs and return a `java Mat` ,

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_generic_cats_ndog_customNativeMethod(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject instance,
        jobject mat1,
        jobject mat2)

// do some operations

return mat1;
```

Knowing that this specific template probabably is already being used by some native method, it would be nice to be able to lookup the JNICALL of those existing implementation for type conversion reference.

Comment: Check [OpenCV Java Tutorials](https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is take java objects (java Mat) and figure out how to pass those objects to a custom native method in c++. I would like to see the existing JNICALL of some opencv methods in order to figure out what's going  under the hood in the prebuilt JNI interface.

Comment: The link provided shows java stuff but does not relate to c++ or JNI